# brew install redis (osx 10.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, redis, homebrew

i tried installing Redis on osx 10.7 via homebrew in bash and I get the following error:

```
==> Downloading http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.9.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.6.9.tar.gz
==> make -C /private/tmp/redis-wQAX/redis-2.6.9/src CC=cc
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var/db
```

Redis is not installed from what i can tell.

```
$ ps -aux | grep redis
ps: No user named 'x'
```

I cannot find the solution and don't know who to ask! Please let me know if you have workaround or solution/suggestion to this. Thank you!

Comment: btw: there's no dash in ps: ps aux | grep redis works for me on OSX10.8, whilst adding the dash returns ps: No user named 'x'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am also using osx 10.7. I think you don't need to install Redis via homebrew. You can just follow the simple instructions in [redis homepage](http://redis.io/download):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

in bash:

```
cd /usr/local/var/
ls
```

the directory 'db' is most likely missing, create it:

```
mkdir db
```

then run

```
brew install redis
```

check /usr/local/var/log

```
ls
```

most likely the directory 'log' is missing, create it

```
mkdir log
brew install redis
```