# Brew Error: File exists

Tags: redis, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm on Yosemite and I have Brew installed. I am trying to install redis and I get the following error. How can I fix it?

```
$ brew install redis
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/redis-2.8.19.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.8.19.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring redis-2.8.19.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
Error: File exists - /usr/local/etc
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://download.redis.io/releases/redis-2.8.19.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/redis-2.8.19.tar.gz
==> make -C /private/tmp/redis-XuZC7r/redis-2.8.19/src CC=clang
Error: File exists - /usr/local/etc
```

Comment: I went and installed it without brew. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498885/brew-install-redis-osx-10-7?answertab=votes#tab-top but i'd love to know why it did not work with it.

Comment: Do you normally use sudo with brew? What happens when you try to install using sudo?

Comment: brew install will not work with root privileges unless brew itself is owned by root

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was asking-- if Brew was owned by root and you were trying to install without using sudo, you'd get an error like that.

Comment: but it's recommended to not be installed under sudo, right?